# Adding Foreign Key to MySQL table errors out: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Can someone shed some light on why MySQL errors out when I try to add a foreign key constraint to a table.

Here are my tables:

```
mysql> desc workflow_stakeholder_sectors;
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| stakeholder_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sector_id      | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc workflow_stakeholder;
+---------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| stakeholder_register            | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| create_date                     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| edit_date                       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country_id                      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| formal_relationship_document_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sector_id                       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type_id                         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| vetting_document_id             | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| approval                        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| approved_by_id                  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| filled_by_id                    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am using macOS Sierra version 10.12.4 and mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for macos10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I use the following mysql statement to add foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `workflow_stakeholder_sectors` ADD CONSTRAINT 
`workflow_stak_stakeholder_id_b87707c1_fk_workflow_stakeholder_id` 
FOREIGN KEY (`stakeholder_id`) REFERENCES `workflow_stakeholder` (`id`);
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely possibilities for the cause of the error are:

- One or both tables are MyISAM or some other storage engine, not InnoDB.

  Kudos to you for at least posting the `DESC` output for your tables,
  but `DESC` doesn't show the storage engine. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` shows
  that information.
- Some row(s) exist in `workflow_stakeholder_sectors` that reference a stakeholder_id value missing from `workflow_stakeholder`. Try the following query:

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM workflow_stakeholder_sectors wss 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN workflow_stakeholder ws
    ON wss.stakeholder_id = ws.id
  WHERE ws.id IS NULL
  ```

Comment: Thank you! as you pointed out the issue was that one table had MYISAM storage engine and another table had innodb.